# Having error in saving image link to the database using pdo

Tags: php, html, ajax, file-upload, pdo

I want to do is make a image uploader system and send the image to `upload` folder and save the link to the database.

My problem is I got this to errors in my `images.php` can anyone help me with this please.

[image]

html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<img id="picture" data-src="#" /> <br />
<input type='file' name="image" id="imgInp" accept="image/*" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#submit').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

        var data = {};

        data.image = $('#imgInp').val();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "images.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {


            }
        });
            return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

images.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents(@$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes(@$_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize(@$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . @$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$location = "upload/" . @$_FILES["image"]["name"];

$q = "INSERT INTO students( image ) VALUES( :image)";

$query = $dbc->prepare($q);
$query->bindParam(':image', $location);


$results = $query->execute();

?>
```

script for image upload:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentSrc = $('#picture').attr('src');
    if(currentSrc==null || currentSrc==""){        
    $('#picture').attr('src','http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e149/eloginko/profile_male_large_zpseedb2954.jpg');

   $("#picture").on('click', function() {
       $("#imgInp").trigger('click')}
   )}


    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#picture').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to get rid of the error messages is to actually place a conditional that checks if `$_FILES` has anything in it. But past that, unclear on the root cause of `$FILES` being empty. In my experience Ajax file uploading with a PHP receiver on the other side just doesn’t work consistently at best. Anyway, here is my version of your code with a conditional in place:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents(@$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = addslashes(@$_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize(@$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . @$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $location = "upload/" . @$_FILES["image"]["name"];

    $q = "INSERT INTO students( image ) VALUES( :image)";

    $query = $dbc->prepare($q);
    $query->bindParam(':image', $location);


    $results = $query->execute();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, it might look like too many if statement, but you need to have checks if you want solid code:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){ 
    $folder = "upload/"; 
    $file = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 
    $full_path = $folder.$file; 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $full_path)) { 
        echo "succesful upload, we have an image!";
        //PDO
        $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
        $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $query = "INSERT INTO students( image ) VALUES( :image)";
        $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':image', $full_path);
        $results = $stmt->execute();
        if($results){
            echo "Insert successful!";
        }else{
             echo "Insert failed!";
        }
    } else { 
       echo "upload received! but process failed";
    } 
}else{ 
    echo "upload failure ! Nothing was uploaded";
}
```

Few things I would like to point out:

- @ suppress error, you don't want that when you troubleshoot, even in
  production, you still want to be aware of the error.
- You should enable error reporting
- You didn't check if php script receives the image upload.
- The use of `file_get_contents` is unclear in this case
- You don't make use of the `$image*` variables ? ....

Comment: got an error with ur code it says:
   Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\myLibrary\pdo_login - Copy - Copy\images.php on line 7
upload failure ! Nothing was uploaded

Comment: @user3763580 it means the PHP file is not getting the file, problem is in the HTML/AJAX code